# interactive C# console as alternative to immediate window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Is there CLI/GUI tool to execute C# code, i.e. alternative for Python ipython/Ruby irb. 
Immediate Windows from Visual Studio is only available during debugging and in some cases can not execute code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

do you mean to execute arbitrary snippets of C# ?

[LinqPad4](http://www.linqpad.net/) is pretty good.

Comment: Yes, I love this tool!

Comment: Now - with debugger!

Answer (score 3):

There is the [CsharpRepl](http://www.mono-project.com/CsharpRepl) project from the mono guys.

And [linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is a very popular option (you don't *have* to use it just for LINQ).

Another option is to use [snippy](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx) by Jon Skeet.